# Why is find showing different ordering on CentOS vs RHEL?

Tags: centos, rhel, find

I have 2 different machines - one running RHEL7 and one running CentOS-7.5.

`find --version` reports version 4.5.11 on each.

I've created the following dierectory structure on each.

```
./dir/some-file
./.hidden/dir/some-file
```

When I run `find -name some-file` on the RHEL7 machine, I get output which matches the above.

But when I run find on my CentOS-7.5 machine, my results list in reversed order.

Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order in which `find` traverses the directory structures of its search paths is probably the order in which [the `readdir()` library function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/readdir.html) returns the directory entries in.  These entries are not further ordered by `find` and will therefore likely depend on the order in which the directory entries were created in the filesystem, and maybe even on the order in which other files and directories on the same partition were created and deleted, depending on the filesystem implementation.

You will get the same ordering in the output of `ls -f`.

Comment: The files were created in the same order on both machines, and each machine is using the ext4 filesystem.

Comment: @DeepDeadpool To get the same order on both systems would be not _quite_ as unexpected as getting the exact same inode numbers for these files and directories on both systems, but close.

Comment: @DeepDeadpool BTW, you can see the inode numbers in the output of `ls -i`.

Comment: Some `find` implementations, under some circumstances at least would order the list of files by inode as an optimisation (to minimize disk head seeks when looking at stat info in the inode table).

Comment: I'll investigate that. I think you're right because I ran my tests a few more times and sometimes the order is not consistent on the RHEL machine. By that I mean that the output listing may sometimes be independent of creation order.

Answer (score 1):

According to the man page for [readdir()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html)

> The order in which filenames are read by successive calls to
>          readdir() depends on the filesystem implementation; it is unlikely
>          that the names will be sorted in any fashion.

This means that the order in which you get the response is really depending on the filesystem, and you can’t expect any order. Most likely you are getting the order in which the entries are stored in the directory structure, and that is not going to be identical from one system to the next because of how the disk is laid out.